# Creating a struct which holds a 2d array of linked lists with custom object

Tags: c, arrays, object, linked-list

im new to C and trying to understand some fundamental stuff.
I'm trying to create a struct which holds an array that consists of linked lists.
Something around this.

```
--------------------------------
|    A    |     B    |    C    |
--------------------------------
      |         |          | 
      V         V          V
   -------    -------    -------
   |  a  |    |  b  |    |  c  |
   -------    -------    -------
      |
      V
   --------
   |  a1  |
   --------
```

Meaning ill have an array which holds the head(A, B and C) of each linked list and each head will hold a pointer to the next node.

I have a struct Object

```
typedef struct Object {
    void* data;
    struct Object* next;
    struct Object* head;
}Object;
```

And a table which holds some more info

```
typedef struct Table {
    Object** arr;
    //More info...//
}Table;
```

I have a function which should create a table with the array.

```
Table* createTable(){

    Table* table = (Table*)malloc(sizeof(struct Table*));

    Object **array = (Object**)malloc(3*sizeof(struct Object*));

    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        array[j] = malloc(sizeof(struct Object));
    }
table->arr = array;
return table;

}
```

But all my memory isn't working as i hoped for, i keep getting an array with just one node.
I guess im still missing some basic stuff.

Thanks

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(struct Table*)`-> `malloc(sizeof(struct Table)`

Comment: ... and what is `size` in `for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)`?

Comment: See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Also, what you are doing is not much different that setting up a hash-table. You may want to look at how the "buckets" (array) hold the head for the "chained" lists that are implemented when collisions occur. `Object **array = malloc (3 * sizeof *array);` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in `Table* table = (Table*)malloc(sizeof(struct Table*))`, which should be `Table* table = malloc(sizeof(struct Table))`.

But the rest of your code is written such that it will create an array of size `3` of pointers to `Object`, and it will initialize this array by letting each element of it point to one `Object` that you create (I suppose that your `size`-variable is initialized somewhere else to `3`, otherwise you now know where to search). So it is clear that you get just one element at each position of your array, you simply do not create more...